# Matriz 4x4 em linguagem C

Tags: c, matriz

Objetivo: Somar duas matrizes 4x4 de números inteiros com o protótipo abaixo, predefinido pelo exercício.

Protótipo que deve ser utilizado:

```
void calc_soma(int* mat_A, int* mat_B, int* mat_C);
```

O protótipo foi feito da seguinte maneira por mim:

```
int i, j;
int valor;

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        valor = *mat_A + *mat_B;
        *mat_C = valor;
    }
}
```

A primeira matriz foi programada da seguinte maneira:

```
printf("\nInforme valores inteiros para os elementos da matriz A: \n");
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%d", &valor);
        mat_A[i][j] = valor;
    }
}
```

E da mesma maneira foi feita a segunda matriz.

O problema é que eu não consigo somar as matrizes. Tentei o seguinte, mas não funcionou:

```
    calc_soma(*mat_A, *mat_B, *mat_C);

printf("\nSoma das matrizes A com B: \n\n");
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        valor = mat_C[i][j];
        printf("%d", valor);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Como posso somar essas duas matrizes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não testei o seu código mas acredito que existam 2 problemas no seu protótipo.
Primero: Na parte de inicialização dos índices - nos laços de repetição - os índices i e j devem  iniciar com o valor zero.
Segundo: as linhas

```
valor = *mat_A + *mat_B;
*mat_C = valor;
```

devem ser substituídas por

```
valor = mat_A[i][j] + mat_B[i][j];
mat_C[i][j] = valor;
```

Quando você usa

```
*mat_A
```

o seu código está acessando apenas a primeira posição do array, isto é, mat_A[0][0].

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Apresenta o seguinte erro:
"a expressão deve possuir tipo ponteiro-para-objeto";

Com o "j" grifado. Sabe o motivo ?

Comment: Olha, se não estou enganado, as matrizes que estão sendo passadas para o método são unidimensionais. Quando você tem um int* mat_A você tem um ponteiro para um int, cada colchete que você usa você "muda" do ponteiro do int para o int em si. Se fosse uma matriz bidimensional, o parâmetro deveria ser int** mat_A, se não estou enganado.

Comment: Então o correto seria declarar as variáveis mat_a, mat_b e mat_c com ** ?

Comment: Ou int mat_A[][]

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!